# How do i unescape a csv file in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file with data kind of like this..
(Edited)

```
"id","data","return_period","return_type","taxable_entity_id","created_at","updated_at","filing_status","exception","fiscal_year","exception_info"
2911,"{\"sup_details\":{\"osup_det\":{\"txval\":1232800.00,\"iamt\":196459.00,\"camt\":12723.00,\"samt\":12723.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_zero\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nil_exmp\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"isup_rev\":{\"txval\":120000.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":10800.00,\"samt\":10800.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nongst\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}},\"itc_elg\":{\"itc_avl\":[{\"ty\":\"IMPG\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"IMPS\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISRC\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":10800.00,\"samt\":10800.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISD\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":4320.00,\"samt\":4320.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_rev\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_net\":{\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":15120.00,\"samt\":15120.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"itc_inelg\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}]},\"tx_pmt\":{\"tx_py\":[{\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"liab_ldg_id\":237161,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}},{\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"liab_ldg_id\":237162,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}}],\"pdcash\":[{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237161\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"ipd\":196459.00,\"cpd\":8403.00,\"spd\":8403.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00},{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237162\",\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"ipd\":0.00,\"cpd\":10800.00,\"spd\":10800.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00}],\"pditc\":{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237161\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"i_pdi\":0.00,\"i_pdc\":0.00,\"i_pds\":0.00,\"c_pdi\":0.00,\"c_pdc\":4320.00,\"s_pdi\":0.00,\"s_pds\":4320.00,\"cs_pdcs\":0.00}},\"intr_ltfee\":{\"ltfee_details\":{\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00}},\"gstin\":\"37ACUPY7876Q1ZR\",\"ret_period\":\"072017\"}","072017","GSTR3B","652704b1-e9e4-4f3f-a1c8-148f076ac2a9","2018-02-05 14:06:28.709000","2018-11-18 05:36:24.625000","FILED",NULL,NULL,NULL
2918,"{\"sup_details\":{\"osup_det\":{\"txval\":1372882.00,\"iamt\":235139.00,\"camt\":5990.00,\"samt\":5990.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_zero\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nil_exmp\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"isup_rev\":{\"txval\":286800.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":25812.00,\"samt\":25812.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nongst\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}},\"itc_elg\":{\"itc_avl\":[{\"ty\":\"IMPG\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"IMPS\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISRC\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":25812.00,\"samt\":25812.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISD\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":50750.00,\"camt\":15515.00,\"samt\":15515.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_rev\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_net\":{\"iamt\":50750.00,\"camt\":41327.00,\"samt\":41327.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"itc_inelg\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}]},\"tx_pmt\":{\"tx_py\":[{\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"liab_ldg_id\":1726731,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}},{\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"liab_ldg_id\":1726732,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}}],\"pdcash\":[{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726731\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"ipd\":92115.00,\"cpd\":0.00,\"spd\":0.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00},{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726732\",\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"ipd\":0.00,\"cpd\":25812.00,\"spd\":25812.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00}],\"pditc\":{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726731\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"i_pdi\":50750.00,\"i_pdc\":46137.00,\"i_pds\":46137.00,\"c_pdi\":0.00,\"c_pdc\":5990.00,\"s_pdi\":0.00,\"s_pds\":5990.00,\"cs_pdcs\":0.00}},\"intr_ltfee\":{\"ltfee_details\":{\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00}},\"gstin\":\"37ACUPY7876Q1ZR\",\"ret_period\":\"082017\"}","082017","GSTR3B","652704b1-e9e4-4f3f-a1c8-148f076ac2a9","2018-02-05 14:07:22.333000","2018-11-18 05:36:25.525000","FILED",NULL,NULL,NULL
1423652,NULL,102018,"GSTR3B","813a92d0-287d-4b6c-a360-7b5e378ed119","2018-11-07 11:31:56.178000","2018-11-09 08:43:38.875000","NOT_FILED","",NULL,NULL
```

How do I unescape the csv file so I can get a workable JSON?

Comment: did you try to read it with `csv` or `pandas` ? Maybe it will give you strings which you can use directly with module `json` and you will not have to unescape them ?

Comment: I've tried to read it with csv but it parses only a part of the json. With pandas I've been able to remove the escape characters but I've not been able to extract the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I open file and replace `'\\"'` with `"'"` and write to temporary file then `csv` has no problem put all JSON strings in one column but strings have wrong single quotations. So I have to replace `"'"` (single) with `'"'` (double) before using with module `json`

```
import csv
import json

data = open('input.csv').read()
data = data.replace('\\"', "'")
open('temp.csv', 'w').write(data)

data = open('temp.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(data)

# skip headers
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv_reader:
    print(json.loads(row[1].replace("'", '"')))
```

---

I can also replace `'\\"'` with unique value ie. `"|"`, and then I can replace other `'"'` (double) with `"'"` (single) and `"|"` with `'"'` so I get correct quotes in JSON columns but I have to use `quotechar="'"` in `csv

```
import csv
import json

data = open('input.csv').read()
data = data.replace('\\"', "|").replace('"', "'").replace('|', '"')
open('temp.csv', 'w').write(data)

data = open('temp.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(data, quotechar="'")

# skip headers
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv_reader:
    print(json.loads(row[1]))))
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have empty strings instead of JSON strings then

use `if/else`

```
for row in csv_reader:

    text = row[1].replace("'", '"')

    if text == 'NULL':
        print("Empty string")
    else:
        print(json.loads(text))
        #pprint.pprint(json.loads(text), indent=2)
```

or `try/except` - it can catch other problems in JSON string

```
for row in csv_reader:

    text = row[1].replace("'", '"')

    try:
        print(json.loads(text))
        #pprint.pprint(json.loads(text), indent=2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Something wrong with JSON:", ex)
```

---

In code I use module `Pretty Print` to display data with indents
    import csv
    import json
    import pprint

```
data = open('input.csv').read()
data = data.replace('\\"', "'")
open('temp.csv', 'w').write(data)

data = open('temp.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(data)

# skip headers
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv_reader:

    text = row[1].replace("'", '"')

    try:
        #print(json.loads(text))
        pprint.pprint(json.loads(text), indent=2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Something wrong with JSON:", ex)
```

---

**EDIT:** I created own csv with some JSON string and it seems csv use `""` instead of `\"` to escape char `"` so this should resolve problem with reading csv with json:

```
import csv

data = open('input.csv').read()

data = data.replace('\\"', '""')

open('temp.csv', 'w').write(data)
```

---

```
import csv
import json

data = open('input.csv').read()
data = data.replace('\\"', '""')
open('temp.csv', 'w').write(data)

data = open('temp.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(data)

# skip headers
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv_reader:

    try:
        print(json.loads(row[1]))
        #pprint.pprint(json.loads(row[1]), indent=2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Something wrong with JSON string:', ex)
        print('row[1]:', row[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. The code above creates a temporary file but it cannot load the json. I'm getting this "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: it means that string is empty and JSON can't convert it. Display this row and add to data in question.

Comment: I've added a row that has no data.. Hopefully this helps

Comment: So it really don't have JSON but NULL - so you have to use `if/else` to check it and skip this line or do something - ie. display warning, save info in log, save row in separated file for checking it later, etc.

Comment: I've added an if-else block to check if the data is NULL and I'm getting no error now. But the single quotes(') isn't being replaced by double-quotes(").

Comment: if you have no error then where do you have single quotes ? JSON with single qoutes should give error when you use `json.loads()`.

Comment: Somehow, I'm not getting any. The single quotes aren't being replaced by double quotes.

Comment: `quotes` are only information that there is text `"123"` instead of number `123` but they are not part of string and you can't see them whey you print string. Do you have problem to use JSON data ?

Comment: I created csv with JSON string and Ifound that csv use `""` instread `\"` so you have to only replace `\"` with `""` to get correct csv file. See code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the file contains double encoded JSON. I tried it parse with Python's `csv` library, but no luck.

But you can use `re` module and then decode json manually. This script prints json data and rest of the line, parsed:

```
import re
import json

with open('file.csv', newline='') as malformed_csvfile:
    next(malformed_csvfile) # skip headers
    for line in malformed_csvfile:
        d1, j, d2 = re.findall(r'^(.*?),(".*?")(,".*)', line)[0]
        json_data = json.loads(json.loads(j))
        rest_of_line = list( map(lambda d: d.strip('"'), (d1.strip() + d2.strip()).split(',') ) )

        print(rest_of_line)
        print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
['2911', '072017', 'GSTR3B', '652704b1-e9e4-4f3f-a1c8-148f076ac2a9', '2018-02-05 14:06:28.709000', '2018-11-18 05:36:24.625000', 'FILED', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL']
{
    "sup_details": {
        "osup_det": {
            "txval": 1232800.0,
            "iamt": 196459.0,
            "camt": 12723.0,
            "samt": 12723.0,
            "csamt": 0.0
        },
        "osup_zero": {
            "txval": 0.0,
            "iamt": 0.0,
            "camt": 0.0,
            "samt": 0.0,
            "csamt": 0.0
        },
        "osup_nil_exmp": {
            "txval": 0.0,
            "iamt": 0.0,
            "camt": 0.0,
            "samt": 0.0,
            "csamt": 0.0
        },
        "isup_rev": {
            "txval": 120000.0,
            "iamt": 0.0,
            "camt": 10800.0,
            "samt": 10800.0,
            "csamt": 0.0
        },
        "osup_nongst": {
            "txval": 0.0,
            "iamt": 0.0,
            "camt": 0.0,
            "samt": 0.0,
            "csamt": 0.0
        }
    },
   ...and so on.
```

`file.csv` contains the text from the question:

```
"id","data","return_period","return_type","taxable_entity_id","created_at","updated_at","filing_status","exception","fiscal_year","exception_info"
2911,"{\"sup_details\":{\"osup_det\":{\"txval\":1232800.00,\"iamt\":196459.00,\"camt\":12723.00,\"samt\":12723.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_zero\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nil_exmp\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"isup_rev\":{\"txval\":120000.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":10800.00,\"samt\":10800.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nongst\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}},\"itc_elg\":{\"itc_avl\":[{\"ty\":\"IMPG\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"IMPS\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISRC\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":10800.00,\"samt\":10800.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISD\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":4320.00,\"samt\":4320.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_rev\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_net\":{\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":15120.00,\"samt\":15120.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"itc_inelg\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}]},\"tx_pmt\":{\"tx_py\":[{\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"liab_ldg_id\":237161,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}},{\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"liab_ldg_id\":237162,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}}],\"pdcash\":[{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237161\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"ipd\":196459.00,\"cpd\":8403.00,\"spd\":8403.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00},{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237162\",\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"ipd\":0.00,\"cpd\":10800.00,\"spd\":10800.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00}],\"pditc\":{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"237161\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"i_pdi\":0.00,\"i_pdc\":0.00,\"i_pds\":0.00,\"c_pdi\":0.00,\"c_pdc\":4320.00,\"s_pdi\":0.00,\"s_pds\":4320.00,\"cs_pdcs\":0.00}},\"intr_ltfee\":{\"ltfee_details\":{\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00}},\"gstin\":\"37ACUPY7876Q1ZR\",\"ret_period\":\"072017\"}","072017","GSTR3B","652704b1-e9e4-4f3f-a1c8-148f076ac2a9","2018-02-05 14:06:28.709000","2018-11-18 05:36:24.625000","FILED",NULL,NULL,NULL
2918,"{\"sup_details\":{\"osup_det\":{\"txval\":1372882.00,\"iamt\":235139.00,\"camt\":5990.00,\"samt\":5990.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_zero\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nil_exmp\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"isup_rev\":{\"txval\":286800.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":25812.00,\"samt\":25812.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"osup_nongst\":{\"txval\":0.00,\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}},\"itc_elg\":{\"itc_avl\":[{\"ty\":\"IMPG\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"IMPS\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISRC\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":25812.00,\"samt\":25812.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"ISD\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":50750.00,\"camt\":15515.00,\"samt\":15515.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_rev\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}],\"itc_net\":{\"iamt\":50750.00,\"camt\":41327.00,\"samt\":41327.00,\"csamt\":0.00},\"itc_inelg\":[{\"ty\":\"RUL\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00},{\"ty\":\"OTH\",\"iamt\":0.00,\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00,\"csamt\":0.00}]},\"tx_pmt\":{\"tx_py\":[{\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"liab_ldg_id\":1726731,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}},{\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"liab_ldg_id\":1726732,\"sgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cgst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"cess\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00},\"igst\":{\"intr\":0.00,\"tx\":0.00,\"fee\":0.00}}],\"pdcash\":[{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726731\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"ipd\":92115.00,\"cpd\":0.00,\"spd\":0.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00},{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726732\",\"trans_typ\":\"30003\",\"ipd\":0.00,\"cpd\":25812.00,\"spd\":25812.00,\"cspd\":0.00,\"i_intrpd\":0.00,\"c_intrpd\":0.00,\"s_intrpd\":0.00,\"cs_intrpd\":0.00,\"i_lfeepd\":0.00,\"c_lfeepd\":0.00,\"s_lfeepd\":0.00,\"cs_lfeepd\":0.00}],\"pditc\":{\"liab_ldg_id\":\"1726731\",\"trans_typ\":\"30002\",\"i_pdi\":50750.00,\"i_pdc\":46137.00,\"i_pds\":46137.00,\"c_pdi\":0.00,\"c_pdc\":5990.00,\"s_pdi\":0.00,\"s_pds\":5990.00,\"cs_pdcs\":0.00}},\"intr_ltfee\":{\"ltfee_details\":{\"camt\":0.00,\"samt\":0.00}},\"gstin\":\"37ACUPY7876Q1ZR\",\"ret_period\":\"082017\"}","082017","GSTR3B","652704b1-e9e4-4f3f-a1c8-148f076ac2a9","2018-02-05 14:07:22.333000","2018-11-18 05:36:25.525000","FILED",NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to find a solution to my problem. Unfortunately, I have got a little more data than just the sample I've provided where a few entries differ from the rest of the data. Hence, the solution is not that simple.